# Parameter is checked against undefined but compiler still warns about TS2532

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, ts-jest

I work on a project where we use DynamoDb to fetch data from it.
One of our queries uses an `:id` parameter to filter the records:

```js
async getJobsFromDatabaseById(id: string): Promise<Job[]> {
  const idParameter = ":id";
  const parameters: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
    //It has been already initialized inside ctor
    /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
    TableName: this.tableName!,
    KeyConditionExpression: `Id = ${idParameter}`
  };

  parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues = {};
  parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter] = id;

  const result = await this.client().query(parameters).promise();
  return this.mapDbRecordsToJobs(result.Items);
}
```

`client()` method returns with an `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` instance.

In the unit test I mock the query in following way:

- During the arrange phase I call the mocking logic and provide an array. The items in it represent those records that are stored in the database (`MockQuery([waitingJob, runningJob, failedJob]);`).
- When the query is issued then inside the mock I use the `:id` parameter to filter the returning data.

```js
import * as AWSMock from "jest-aws-sdk-mock";

...
//This type alias is introduced to avoid the usage of `Object`
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars*/
type DatabaseRecord = Record<string, unknown>;
...

const idParameter = ":id"; //I know this is tight-coupling to implementation
const MockQuery = (records: Array<DatabaseRecord>): void => {
  AWSMock.mock(
    "DynamoDB.DocumentClient",
    "query",
    (
      _parameters: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput,
      callback: (
        error: AWS.AWSError | undefined,
        data: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryOutput
      ) => void
    ) => {
      let filteredRecords: DatabaseRecord[] = records;
      if (
        _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues &&
        _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
      ) {
        /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
        filteredRecords = records.filter(
          record => record.Id === _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues![idParameter]
        );
      }

      const output: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryOutput = {
        Items: filteredRecords
      };
      callback(undefined, output);
    }
  );
};
```

My problem is that I have to use the non-null-assertion operator even though I checked the objects against `undefined`.
This works fine:

```js
if (
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues &&
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
) {
  /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
  filteredRecords = records.filter(
    record => record.Id === _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues![idParameter]
  );
}
```

But this gives me the **TS2532 error**: *Object is possibly `undefined`*:

```js
if (
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues &&
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
) {
  filteredRecords = records.filter(
    record => record.Id === _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
  );
}
```

---

I've tried to reproduce the same problem without relying on the DynamoDb:

```js
interface Test {
    Parameters? : {[key: string]: any}
}

function GetData() : Test {
    return {
    Parameters: {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2
    }
   };
}

function PrintData(data: Test){
    if(data.Parameters)
    {
        console.log(data.Parameters["x"])
    }
}

var data = GetData();
PrintData(data);
```

It does work without any error.

What do I have to change in order to avoid the usage of non-null-assertion operator?

---

**UPDATE**: [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

Even though optional chaining will not raise an eslint warning it still feels weird:

```js
if (
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues &&
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
) {
  filteredRecords = records.filter(
    record => record.Id === _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues?.[idParameter]
  );
}
```

Comment: maybe it considers _parameters for possible null. Have you tried if (_parameters &&
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues &&
  _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues[idParameter]
)

Comment: @Boug Yes, I've tried as well, but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have ended up to use optional chaining like this:

```js
const idParamValue = _parameters.ExpressionAttributeValues?.[idParameter];

if (idParamValue) {
  filteredRecords = records.filter(record => record.Id === idParamValue);
}
```